# C client/server project

Tags: c, unix, process, client-server

I need to implement a client / server project in C that simulates the work of an information office .The server has three processes operators who read three different files.
Each operator is responsible for a single function. A user typically requests a file from one of the three operators, and the operator responds by sending the contents of the requested file (if existing). After receipt, the client displays on the terminal the file in question.
The number of processes is limited and predefined operators: all operators are
created upon startup execution. Each operator serves a request for a time,
pulling it out from a queue.
The interaction then takes place between two types of processes: those that provide the files and those that require the file (it is customers who require offices to provide them with text documents).
Do you have any idea on how to do the job?
On how to structure a generator of client processes and the file server.
Thanks

Comment: Install [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to help you to be creative.

Comment: Do you really HAVE to use plain C for this sort of stuff?  It's much easier with classes.

Comment: It's not a problem of classes, this kind of problem is very old. Elegant solution exists in C, Pascal, ADA 83... too.

Comment: I need to do it in C because it's a work for the school

Comment: Obviously you are going to generate your workers with `fork`.  It's less clear if the parent process is responsible for creating clients (i.e. customers) but if so then...it's more `fork`ing.  You don't specify anything so I guess it is up to you on what kind of IPC you are going to use between your workers/boss and operators/clients so that is a decision you need to consider.